# python: iterate dictionary sorted by key as int

Tags: python

I have a python dictionary:

```
steps = {"5":{}, "1":{}}
```

I need to iterate this, but sorted by the keys as though they were ints. Key is always a number.

I tried:

```
def get_key_as_int(key):
    return int(key)

for key in sorted(steps.items(), key=lambda t: get_key_as_int(t[0])):
    step = steps[key]
```

but I get an error:

```
 unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> steps = {"5":{}, "1":{}}
>>> for k in sorted(steps, key=int):
        print k, steps[k]


1 {}
5 {}
```

Answer (score 0):

`steps.items()` returns key,value pairs(a list of tuples) not just keys. So in your code you were actually trying to do :

`step = steps[ ('1', {}) ]`

which will raise an error because keys can't contain mutable items.

Correct version of your code:

```
for key,step in sorted(steps.items(), key=lambda t: get_key_as_int(t[0])):
    #do something with step
```